# Font-family in TinyMCE

Tags: fonts, tinymce, font-family

I have the root for the place where I've stored the files with my external fonts: tinymce >> advanced >> fonts. I have the next fonts: GothamBold, GothamLight and I don't know how to integrate in editor in style_formats I have something like `{title: 'GothamBold', inline: 'span', styles: { 'font-family':'GothamBold'}}` and appears in Formats but when i'm trying to apply the font not working.

Comment: Are you loading the font in the `content_css`? If the font is not available in the browser assigning it to something won't cause it to load properly.

Comment: I solved the problem creating a content_css. Thanks!